# Large, 1 bit-per-pixel bitmap causes OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, out-of-memory

What I'd like to do is to load an image from disk and create a `BitmapSource` from it.
The image is 14043px x 9933px and is b/w (1bpp). But I run into a `OutOfMemoryException` because the following code consumes about 800 MB RAM.

The following code generates an `ImageSource` in the dimensions of my specific file. 
I did this to see if I could make it work without using the actual file on my disk.

```
public System.Windows.Media.ImageSource getImageSource(){

    int width = 14043;
    int height = 9933;

    List<System.Windows.Media.Color> colors = new List<System.Windows.Media.Color>();
    colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Black);
    colors.Add(System.Windows.Media.Colors.White);

    BitmapPalette palette = new BitmapPalette(colors);
    System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pf = System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Indexed1;

    int stride = width / pf.BitsPerPixel;

    byte[] pixels = new byte[height * stride];

    for (int i = 0; i < height * stride; ++i)
    {
         if (i < height * stride / 2)
         {
               pixels[i] = 0x00;
         }
         else
         {
               pixels[i] = 0xff;
         }
    }

    BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
      width,
      height,
      96,
      96,
      pf,
      palette,
      pixels,
      stride);



    return image;
}
```

In my calculation the image should consume about 16.7 MB.
Also, I cannot specify a cache option when using BitmapSource.create. But the image must be cached on load.

The return value of this method is set as the source of an image control.

---

**ISSUE REOPENED**

After @Clemens posted the answer, wich worked very well in the first place. I noticed a very bad behaviour while inspecting my TaskManager. This is the code I am using, it is excatly the same as @Clemens answer.

```
public ImageSource getImageSource(){
   var width = 14043;
   var height = 9933;

   var stride = (width + 7) / 8;
   var pixels = new byte[height * stride];

   for (int i = 0; i < height * stride; i++){
      pixels[i] = 0xAA;
   }

   WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.BlackWhite, null);
   bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), pixels, stride, 0);
   bitmap.Freeze();
   return bitmap;
}
```

Before running any code, my taskmanager shows the following: (1057 MB free)
[image]

After starting the app it turnes out that this method has a very high peak of memory usage: (497 MB free after initial peak)
[image: Clemens Solution]

I tried a couple things and found out that @Clemens routine probably isn't the problem. I changed the code to this:

```
private WriteableBitmap _writeableBitmap; //Added for storing the bitmap (keep it in scope)

public ImageSource getImageSource(){
   var width = 14043;
   var height = 9933;

   var stride = (width + 7) / 8;
   var pixels = new byte[height * stride];

   for (int i = 0; i < height * stride; i++){
      pixels[i] = 0xAA;
   }

   _writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.BlackWhite, null);
   _writeableBitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), pixels, stride, 0);
   _writeableBitmap.Freeze();
   return null; //Return null (Image control source will be set to null now but bitmap still stored in private field)
}
```

I wanted to keep the bitmap in memory but not affect the image control, this is the result: (997 MB free)
(As you can see, the blue line increases just a tiny bit at the right side)
[image: Clemens Solution Modified]

With this knowledge I believe there is something wrong with my image control as well. The peak starts when the writeableBitmap is assigned to the image control. This is all my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TifFileViewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TifFileViewer"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="563" Width="1046">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Image x:Name="imageControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What were you calculating? (formular)

Comment: If your image is 32bits ARGB, there will be 4 byte/pixel and the image will consume 14043*9933*4 = 532Mo.

Comment: Get it, it's a black and white image, so 8 pixel/byte. Indeed it leads to 16.7 MB.

Comment: @SebastianL 14043px x 9933px are 139489119 pixels in total (or bits) are 17436139 bytes are 17027 kbytes are 16.7 mbytes

Comment: Btw there is a PixelFormats.BlackWhite :o)

Comment: @Orace You're right. I tried this as well. But after it resulted in the same issue I went back to the code above, hehe

Comment: I run your code and it *only* consume 200MB... I have no idea of what is going on ...

Comment: Do you run on a 64 bits system ? mine is 32 bits.

Comment: @Orace Nope 32 as well... Without calling this method my app consumes less than 20 MB, soo the 800 MB must come from the code above. Strange that it performs a little better at your system.

Comment: @Orace I changed my xaml a little and am able to lower the usage to 280 MB. However, the image is not cached on load (Not visible in image control) But when I resize the window (force caching) i get the memory exception again.

Comment: I bet the framework try to convert the image to 32 bits ARGB before showing it.
No more ideas, good luck !

Comment: Do you only run out of memory if you try to *display* the image?  Any image rendered in WPF is likely converted to bgra32 in order to be compatible with the Direct3D surfaces WPF uses.

Comment: See my answer for a fix :D

Comment: Do you have a full repro project somewhere so everyone talks about the 100% same program?

Comment: If the image is in fact a file, the best is really to do: var img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your file path")). This way you don't have to specify anything (and the freezing is implicit). In this case, you should see a 13M allocation if you don't assign to the control, and 30M if you assign it.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the OutOfMemory exception has nothing to do with the available RAM. It depends on the Virtual Memory (which is limited to 2 or 4 GB per 32-bit process). You can view the process' virtual memory amount via 3rd-party apps like Process Explorer or Process Hacker

Comment: @SimonMourier That was my first attempt. But it throws the Exception immediatly. .Net is not able to display my image when the source is directly applied or set as a URI. Anyway, I will update this post with a additional solution as soon as I can fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important that you **freeze** the bitmap. Also, since you are using a 1 bit per pixel format, you should calculate the pixel buffer's stride as `width / 8`.

The following method creates a bitmap with pixels set to alternating black and white.

```
public ImageSource CreateBitmap()
{
    var width = 14043;
    var height = 9933;

    var stride = (width + 7) / 8;
    var pixels = new byte[height * stride];

    for (int i = 0; i < height * stride; i++)
    {
        pixels[i] = 0xAA;
    }

    var format = PixelFormats.Indexed1;
    var colors = new Color[] { Colors.Black, Colors.White };
    var palette = new BitmapPalette(colors);

    var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(
        width, height, 96, 96, format, palette, pixels, stride);

    bitmap.Freeze(); // reduce memory consumption
    return bitmap;
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `BlackWhite` format without a BitmapPalette:

```
    var format = PixelFormats.BlackWhite;

    var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(
        width, height, 96, 96, format, null, pixels, stride);
```

---

**EDIT:**
If you create a `WriteableBitmap` instead of using `BitmapSource.Create` the large bitmap also works with an Image control in a Zoombox:

```
public ImageSource CreateBitmap()
{
    ...
    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, format, palette);
    bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), pixels, stride, 0);
    bitmap.Freeze();
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: (oops, intended to post before you but you've been faster) problem with your code : the process uses nearly 580Mb of memory :D

Comment: Also, while your idea is indeed correct regarding `WriteableBitmap` ,you can see that it will invariably push the process to eat the same memory as the first case; just step through that line and see the Task Manager.

Comment: @Aybe Just freeze the bitmap. Now my test application consumes less than 30 MB.

Comment: +1 Great answer, I should think more about freezing objects... the thing is the 'freezing' aspect is really neglected in the docs so we tend to ignore it while it is indeed very powerful.

Comment: +1 Because it solves the issue. Problem is that I use a Zoom and Pan functionality which leads to a memory exception again. But INITIAL RAM consumption indeed is 30 MB! If anybody wants to keep solving this: I am using ZoomBox from here: https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: "Problem is that I use a Zoom and Pan functionality which leads to a memory exception again." That is certainly another question. Regarding what has been asked *here*, this is the answer.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the edit. It really works. And yes, pan and zoom was not part of the question, sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @Clemens I put on the happy face too early. There still is a heavy memory peak when assigning the writeable bitmap to the control. I updated my question and added a bounty worth 50 points.

Comment: I'd suggest to ask a new question. This one has already been answered.

Comment: *Why* is it important to freeze the bitmap? What effects does freezing have? It's already established that it solves the issue, but *why*?

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT: I'd conclude that this is a DIY approach since as @Clemens cleverly pointed out in his answer, freezing the bitmap does the same but with a one-liner.**

*You really need to get your hands dirty to achieve what you're looking for* ;)

### Explanations

(with correction from @Clemens)

The .NET framework doesn't treat less than 8 bit-per-pixel images very well. It systematically converts them to 32BPP which in my case brought my process to nearly 200Mb. Read here it's a bug or it's by design.

Whether using `WriteableBitmap` (with/without pointers) or `BitmapSource.Create` it will consume that much memory, **BUT**; there's only one place (`BitmapImage`) where it's behaving appropriately and fortunately it's a critical place for achieving what you're looking for!

**Note:** the framework will accept less than or equal to 8 bits per pixel images only if 1 byte equals 1 pixel. As you and I are seeing this, **a 1 bit per pixel image means 1 byte = 8 pixels**; I've followed this norm. While some could say this as a bug, it's probably a convenience for the dev for not dealing with bits directly.

### Solution

(specifically for a 1BPP image)

As I said, you will have to get your hands dirty but I'll explain everything so you should get up and running pretty quickly ;)

**What I did:**

- Generated the image manually at 1BPP (which is effectively 17Mb)
- wrote that result to a .PNG file
- created a `BitmapImage` out of that PNG file

The application memory usage does not go up, actually it gets to 60Mb but goes down to 35Mb shortly later probably because the garbage collector collects the `byte[]` used initially. Anyway it never reaches 200 nor 800 Mb as you've experienced!

[image]

[image]

**What you need (.NET 4.5)**

- download the PNGCS library from https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/
- rename `Pngcs45.dll` to `Pngcs.dll` otherwise a `FileNotFoundException` will occur
- add a reference to that DLL
- use the code below

**Why did I use PNGCS?**

Because the same issues as laid out above apply to `PngBitmapEncoder` from WPF since it relies on `BitmapFrame` for adding content to it.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Hjg.Pngcs;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int width = 14043;
            int height = 9933;
            int stride;
            byte[] bytes = GetBitmap(width, height, out stride);
            var imageInfo = new ImageInfo(width, height, 1, false, true, false);

            PngWriter pngWriter = FileHelper.CreatePngWriter("test.png", imageInfo, true);
            var row = new byte[stride];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                int offset = y*stride;
                int count = stride;
                Array.Copy(bytes, offset, row, 0, count);
                pngWriter.WriteRowByte(row, y);
            }
            pngWriter.End();

            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("test.png", UriKind.Relative);
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            Image1.Source = bitmapImage;
        }

        private byte[] GetBitmap(int width, int height, out int stride)
        {
            stride = (int) Math.Ceiling((double) width/8);
            var pixels = new byte[stride*height];
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    var color = (byte) (y < height/2 ? 0 : 1);
                    int byteOffset = y*stride + x/8;
                    int bitOffset = x%8;
                    byte b = pixels[byteOffset];
                    b |= (byte) (color << (7 - bitOffset));
                    pixels[byteOffset] = b;
                }
            }

            return pixels;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can enjoy your 1BPP image.

Comment: Both `PixelFormats.Indexed1` and `PixelFormats.BlackWhite` (not `BlackAndWhite`) use one bit per pixel.

Comment: Thank you Aybe! It works really well! I guess there is no way around the png file stored on the disk, right?   :( Because I am loading a tif and the pngcs library will save it as a png before displaying it as a bitmap. The reason why I need to access the pixel data is because I have to manipulate the image before display. You don't have to work this out, since you pretty much solved the issue. I will accept the answer anyway :D

Comment: Glad to see it helped ! A quick search brought up the following library for TIFF : http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/ (haven't tested it though)