# Memorystream - OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, bitmap, memorystream

It might be that this question has been answered before, but I found no good solution to my problem.

I am trying to convert a Bitmap to a bytearray using a memory stream, but when I do so I get an out of memory exception, and I can't figure out where and what is going wrong. Below you can find my code, and I would be very grateful for any insight on the topic.

```
static byte[] convertBmpToByteArray(string imageFilePath)
    {
        Bitmap bmpImg = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(imageFilePath);
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bmpImg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);

                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: My image is about 600 kB.

Comment: [I asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26300379/large-1-bit-per-pixel-bitmap-causes-outofmemoryexception) a while ago. Many people have problems with images and memory. You **might** need to freeze the bitmap.

Comment: You should dispose the `bmpImg` when you're done processing it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This thread can be closed as I found out that the problem was located elsewhere in my code.

Comment: The OP self-resolved this issue - Please vote to close this question: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.